# pickle updates the class definition of contained objects but dill does not

Tags: python, pickle, dill

dill updates the class definition of the dilled/undilled object itself, but not the class definition of objects contained by the dilled/undilled object.

pickle does update the class definition in either case.

Why does dill not follow the same behavior as pickle?

### pickle

```
import os
import pickle
import tempfile
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


def pickle_save(x):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        pickle.dump(x, f)
    return f


def pickle_load(f):
    with open(f.name, "rb") as f:
        x = pickle.load(f)
    os.unlink(f.name)
    return x


@dataclass
class B:
    attribute: str = "old"

    def method_1(self):
        print(f"old class: {self.attribute=}")


@dataclass
class A:
    attribute_1: str = "old"
    instances_of_B: list[B] = field(default_factory=list)

    def method_1(self):
        print(f"old class: {self.attribute_1=}, {self.instances_of_B=}")

    def add_b_instance(self):
        self.instances_of_B.append(B())


old_a = A()
old_a.add_b_instance()
old_a.method_1()
old_a.instances_of_B[0].method_1()
print(f"{old_a = }")
temp_file = pickle_save(old_a)

# old_a has been saved to file
# Next we update our class definitions
# then load old_a from file,
# and see whether the added methods exist

@dataclass
class A:
    attribute_1: str = "new"
    attribute_2: str = "new attribute 2"
    instances_of_B: list[B] = field(default_factory=list)

    def method_1(self):
        print(f"new class: {self.attribute_1=}, {self.instances_of_B=}")

    def method_2(self):
        print("this method from A did not exist before")
        print(f"this attribute did not exist before: {self.attribute_2=}")


@dataclass
class B:
    attribute: str = "new"

    def method_1(self):
        print(f"new class: {self.attribute=}")

    def method_2(self):
        print("this method from B did not exist before")


new_a = pickle_load(temp_file)
print(f"{new_a=}")
new_a.method_1()
new_a.method_2()
new_a.instances_of_B[0].method_1()
new_a.instances_of_B[0].method_2()
```

The new method_2 of both the pickled A instance and the contained B instance can be used after loading:

```
old class: self.attribute_1='old', self.instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')]
old class: self.attribute='old'
old_a = A(attribute_1='old', instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')])
new_a=A(attribute_1='old', attribute_2='new attribute 2', instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')])
new class: self.attribute_1='old', self.instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')]
this method from A did not exist before
this attribute did not exist before: self.attribute_2='new attribute 2'
new class: self.attribute='old'
this method from B did not exist before
```

### dill

```
import dill as pickle
```

The new method_2 of only the pickled A instance can be used after loading, while the new method_2 of the contained B instance cannot:

```
old class: self.attribute_1='old', self.instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')]
old class: self.attribute='old'
old_a = A(attribute_1='old', instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')])
new_a=A(attribute_1='old', attribute_2='new attribute 2', instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')])       
new class: self.attribute_1='old', self.instances_of_B=[B(attribute='old')]
this method from A did not exist before
this attribute did not exist before: self.attribute_2='new attribute 2'
old class: self.attribute='old'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\question_dill_pickle.py", line 78, in <module>
    new_a.instances_of_B[0].method_2()
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'method_2'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `dill` author.  `dill` doesn't follow the behavior of `pickle` here, because `pickle` serializes the class by reference (i.e. it has no choice, but use whatever class definition is used in the current context), while `dill` stores the class definition along with the pickled instance... so you can choose the behavior. The default is to use the stored class, so you get what you pickle (more commonly, this is what is desired). However, if you want to ignore the stored class, and use the updated definition, you can use the `ignore=True` keyword in `load` (or change it globally in `dill.settings`).

From the docs:

> ```
> If *ignore=False* then objects whose class is defined in the module
> *__main__* are updated to reference the existing class in *__main__*,
> otherwise they are left to refer to the reconstructed type, which may
> be different.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for dill and for your answer. Both `pickle.settings.update({"ignore": True})` and `x = pickle.load(f, ignore=True)` fail with the same error. But `pickle.settings.update({"byref": True})` does remove the error, regardless of whether `ignore` is set to `True` or `False` (in `settings` or in-line in `load`). Using dill 0.3.5.1, python 3.9.7, Win10 if that matters.

Comment: `byref=True` is essentially the same serialization behavior as `pickle`, so that's not surprising.